# Use variable from date as key value in hash to print with Twig

Tags: twig

I'm trying to print different messages based on the date:

```
{% set message = { 28: 'foo', 29: 'bar' } %} {# each date has a message #}
{% set date = now | date("d") %}
{{message.date}}
```

However, `{{message.date}}` is not giving the expected result.

Is it a formatting issue or something larger?

Comment: Kindly clarify what is the expected result and what is the result you are getting instead?

Comment: I was hoping to see "foo" or "bar" displayed if it was the 28th or 29th of the month respectively. However, due to improper formatted (see below for answer), it returned nothing – just blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the array properly:

```
{{ message[date] }}
```

Make sure you handle the "missing day" case:

```
{{ message[date]|default('no data for given day') }}
```

Or only render if the data is defined:

```
{% if message[date] is defined %}
    {{ message[date] }}
{% endif %}
```

The choice is yours.

Comment: Or `{{ message[date] | default ? message[date] }}`